# How to reduce video file size in android?

Tags: android, video-capture

I am working on social networking android application where I need to share video file captured from camera. But when I upload it on server it takes too much time to upload due to large video file size. I used Samsung Galaxy S4 which has 13megapixel camera and which captured around 122MB video file in 60 second.

So due to this my upload time is too large. Can any one suggest me how I can reduce video file  size, I don't want high quality video.

To start camera I used following code, I also try with camera 'videoQuality' intent flag which is commented on my code, but not getting result.

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", VIDEO_DURATION);  
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.videoQuality",1);
    //    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT,10485760);
    //    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,0);

startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_ACTIVITY);
```

Comment: where is your current codes?

Comment: I update my question with code please check.

Comment: Hey bro actually O is for low quality video and 1 is for high quality video- checkout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA

Comment: You can also specify time limit and maximum size while capturing video

Comment: @JIGAR PANDYA: 'maximum size' will stop recording & time will miss application time limit which is 2.5 minutes.

Comment: intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.videoQuality",0); -- use this to capture low quality video

Comment: @JIGAR PANDYA: We also try with 'intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.videoQuality",0)' but still video file size is too large it is upto 100MB.

Comment: yes i know it wont affect.the other possible solution is to reduce the resolution of camera programmatically to capture low sized videos here is code snipper for same - http://xmodulo.com/2013/02/how-to-change-camera-resolution-programmatically-in-android.html

Comment: But for that we need to build custom camera application, I don't want to do this.  Is it possible to set device default camera application resolution.

Comment: Hi Amol. Did you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: @Tiago: We used custom camera to reduced size. For default camera I haven't find any solutions to reduce video size.

Comment: custom camera is only one solution!!!

Comment: You can use custom camera to reduce video file. follow This Link http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/28/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-for-your-camera-in-android/

Answer (score 3):

```
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
```

This is only 3 MB to get only 1 sec video

```
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,-1);
```

This is the best solution for video compression. Its worked 3 MB data to get 2 minutes video compressed

Comment: Sir can you give example please.